# arduino and GSM shield

Tags: arduino, gsm

I wanted to connect arduino mega with GSM shield(mounting) and a ultrasound sensor with a battery(9V) to post data and send SMS. but it was working for 10 minutes and stops working i.e the lights are on but the signal is not constant(checked with all the networks and signal strengths : no issues there). It is working properly with new battery for 10 minutes(tested with several new batteries)Is this power issue. If yes, please help me resolve this issue.

-Is GSM shield mounting creating the problem?
-how to get a long battery life with arduino and GSM shield.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

This is power issue, GSM modem uses 1W (200mA at 5V) of power on 850/900 MHz, and 2W on 1800/1900 MHz, and GSM shield requires peaks of up to 2A current.
You need more batteries or dc power supply.